# How to join repeated column JPA Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

I have 2 fields and such connections:

```
@ManyToOne(targetEntity = Coordinate.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="coordinate_id")
private Coordinate startRouteCoordinateId; 

@ManyToOne(targetEntity = Coordinate.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="coordinate_id")
private Coordinate endRouteCoordinateId;
```

But I get the error: Repeated column in mapping for entity

How can I use 2 fields of the same class in Hibernate?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

@ManyToOne basically means that entity that has those 2 fields can be presented in many coordinates.

Example:

```
@Entity
public class SomeEntity { 
   @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Coordinate.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   @JoinColumn(name="coordinate_id")
   private Coordinate startRouteCoordinateId; 
}
```

In this example you have: `MANY SomeEntity` -> `ONE Coodinate` by `coordinate_id` column in SomeEntity's table.

So that why it's only makes sense to map it to single (ONE) Coordinate by `coordinate_id` column.
Probably you have misunderstanding of what ONE should map to which MANys in your case.

Comment: No, I need two coordinates start and end. I just wrong specified name of JoinColumn.

@JoinColumn(name="start_route_coordinate_id")

@JoinColumn(name="end_route_coordinate_id")